# Magento product gallery image size

Tags: php, magento

I can't find the way to change the size of the product gallery images when enlarged in the popup window. At the moment they are automatically resized by Magento to a 600x600 resolution, but I want them to show at a higher resolution (1000x1000).

This is an example from my website:

Product gallery:

http://www.finestlighters.com/en/st-dupont-xtend-maxijet-007-casino-royale-chrome.html

and enlarged picture

http://www.finestlighters.com/en/catalog/product/gallery/id/109/image/2305/

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

you can change this by editing in file `app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml`
where you will find code like -

```
$_imageUrl = $this->helper('catalog/image')
                    ->init($_product, 'image', $_image->getFile())
                    ->keepFrame(false)
                    ->constrainOnly(true)
                    ->resize(600);
```

change the value in `resize()` to resize image of desired resolution

Comment: Thank you Piyush. Unfortunately if I change that value (that is set at the moment at 265) I resize the product image instead of the popup image. Any other hint?